# Wordpress user registration to upload data for admins approval

Tags: database, wordpress, post, admin, registration

I want that users be able to upload info, this info will be show on a product list but it will only be posted if the admins approve it.

The user may need to register or not, the contact info will be on the info they upload.

Do i need to storage the info on a different database? can i do this with the wordpress registration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wordpress database table user to store data, set post_status as 'pending', so that admin can check and can change its status to 'publish'

You can create custom template page, then insert user data in post table using custom query or 
wp_insert_post() function.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!!!!

Comment: Yes, it helps. I need it to be sure if i was in the right direction. Thanks.